# Parallelism in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I'm trying to create a simple example doing a parallel evaluations:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

main = do
  runEval $ do
    a <- rpar (\x -> x + 5)
    b <- rseq (\x -> x + 15)
    return (a, b)
```

It says

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t0'
                with actual type `(Integer -> Integer, Integer -> Integer)'
```

I know, it's not related to parallelism in Haskell, but nonetheless, how do I build such a simple example in Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are using the lambdas. The types of `rpar` and `rseq` is `a -> Eval a` but the lambdas you passed has obviously type `Integer -> Integer` because you didn't passed an argument to the lambdas.

Something like this compiles (also note that you need to print the result):

```
main = do
    print $ runEval $ do
        a <- rpar $ (\x -> x + 5) 4
        b <- rseq $ (\x -> x + 15) 4
        return (a, b)
```

To learn more about parallel processing in Haskell. There is a great book called ["Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026365.do) by Simon Marlow, the HTML version is available for free [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/index.html):

Comment: by the way, why is it necessary to use "$" at runEval $ do ?

Comment: @Alex The `$` is called the apply operator, and essentially exists to get rid of parens.  `f $ x` is the same as `f (x)`, and `g $ f $ x` is the same as `g (f (x))`.  Everything to the right of it gets wrapped in parens and passed to whatever is to the left.

Comment: @Alex If you're new to Haskell I recommend you to read "Learn you a Haskell for Great Good!", its available online too: http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Comment: @bheklilr, I know this. I'm asking, why do I have to use it in runEval $ do in particular?

Comment: @Alex because otherwise it would appear that the entire argument to `runEval` is simply `do`.  By using `$`, it forces the entire do block to be to be passed into `runEval`, although in Rodrigo's example he really needs to indent the last three lines more.

Comment: Actually, it's purely part of haskell syntax. `do` blocks can't be used in any expression context - only as the first thing in the expression. However, all binary operators treat each of their arguments as a full expression, so you can put a do block on the right side of one.

Comment: @bheklilr, but `runEval :: Eval a -> a` takes only one argument, why does it need $?

Comment: @Alex The expression `do { a <- rpar $ (+5) 4; b <- rseq $ (+15) 4; return (a, b); }` is passed as that single argument, thanks to the `$` between `runEval` and `do`.  Without that `$`, the compiler sees it as `do {print $ runEval do; ... }`, with the word `do` being literally the only argument to `runEval`.  If you defined a separate function that was equivalent to the inner do block: `f = do { a <- rpar $ (+5) 4; b <- rseq $ (+15) 4; return (a, b); }`, then `main` could simply be `print $ runEval f`.